# Setup for .net 4.0 application

Tags: .net, windows-installer

My desktop application requires .net 4.0 full package. Why full package?
I am using next api that belongs to full package.

- System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor
- HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
- HttpUtility.UrlEncode
- HttpUtility.UrlDecode

Then even I have set in setup project requirements only for .net 4.0 full package, during install this setup shows dialog that requires .net 4.0 client package installation, and then full package.

It looks like end user will be forced to install both packages?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places where target framework should be set

- Detected Dependencies -> Microsoft
  .Net Framework -> Property
- Setup Project Properties -> Prerequisites...